# How to use Pipe (|) in powershell -Command ...?

Tags: powershell, cmd, console

I would like to execute powershell commands from a Windows console commandline. My method is:

```
c:\>powershell -Command mypowershellstatment1;mypowershellstatment1;etc
```

**Issue:**

In case if a complex powershell command contains powershell pipe operator, then it seems that Windows console interprets it, instead of passing it literally as parameter to the powershell executable.

For example:

```
c:\>powershell -Command mypowershellstatment1 | anything;mypowershellstatment1;etc
```

gives the standard console error message *"'anything' is not recognized as an internal or external command"*
operable program or batch file.

**Question**

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Escape `|` with `^`: `Get-Something ^| Do-Something`

Comment: Note that if you are running things directly from the commandline and not creating a commandline script of some sort, you can simply type ```powershell``` first and then you will be prompted with ```PS >``` prompt where you can enter any powershell commands you want natively without having to worry about escaping.

Comment: Why is your `-Command` value not surrounded in double quotes? It is a command string.

Comment: @Efie because it is an Azure provisioning extension, I will not there to "simply type powershell first"

Comment: @AdminOfThings Because the statements full of both double and single quotes themself

Comment: You can use single quotes inside double quotes in PowerShell without escaping, you can escape double quotes with a backtick character like this: ```"This won't fail even though it has `"nested strings`""```

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Many thx. This is an answer, I should search for "what is the escape character in [windows] command line. In case you post it, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `|` has a similar function in cmd, you need to escape it.

In cmd, the appropriate escape sequence would be `^|`:

```
C:\>powershell -Command Get-Something ^| Do-Something
```

Answer (score -1):

powershell "command1 | command2 | command3... | commandN-1 | commandN"